Is it native to ask questions with `what are ...'?
For example, is it native to ask 'What are some good books to read?'
I have studied to ask like 'Can you suggest me some good books to read?', but I
came across this 'what are' usage. Is it native?
This might be a duplicate question, but I didn't find one - it would be also
great if links to same questions can be provided.

By the way, it is not idiomatic to use the word native as you have done. The idiomatic term for what you mean is idiomatic.

@PaulTanenbaum Thanks :)))

When I type into Google the string what are some, the searches it proposes back to me are

what are some examples of permanent records
what are some characteristics
what are some good movies to watch
what are some hobbies

In this case, Google is successfully generating English-language strings that are perfectly idiomatic.
So yes, the way you have expressed your question, “What are some good books to read?” is fine.

Side note: You are mis-using the word "native" here. "Native" means "coming from this place". You can use it as a noun, like, "Winston Churchill was a native of Britain". Or you can use it as an adjective, like, "A popular native practice is drinking guava juice." But you seem to be using it to mean, "something that native speakers say". So what you should have written was, "Would a native speaker say ...", or more naturally, "Would a fluent speaker say ..." or "Is it idiomatic to say ..." But to get to your question ...
"What are some good books to read?" is perfectly good and idiomatic.
You could say, "What are some good books for me to read?" But this is only necessary if, in context, there might be some question whether you mean you or someone else. Like if you were talking about good books for your children versus good books for yourself.
"Can you suggest me some good books?" is not correct. The object of suggest, the word or words that should follow it, are what is suggested, not who it is suggested to. "Me" here would be an indirect object, and should follow a preposition, like "to" or "for". So for example, "Can you suggest some good books for me?" "Suggest me" means that the thing being suggested is "me". Like, "My company is going to hire a new accountant." "Oh, can you suggest me?"

It seems to be idiomatic in the US, but it would be out-of-place in formal English in the UK. Even in everyday English,
"Could you suggest some good books for me to read?"
or
"Could you recommend some books for me to
read?"
might be more idiomatic. (I dropped the 'good' from the second suggestion as 'recommend' seems to cover it!)

Really? I'm curious why. Perhaps it's less about the "what are" and more about how well it's suited to this open-ended subjective situation? There would be nothing wrong with "What are Jane Austen's best-known novels," would there?

@AndyBonner  "What are Jane Austen's best-known novels," sounds really idiomatic to me. It just sounds like how I was asked by teachers, or in a test. But I feel different with 'what are' questions like 'What are some good books to read', so I asked this. :D

@Limina102 Generally, you can understand “what are ___” as “please list ___.” In my opinion, it’s a reasonable way to ask for recommendations. i’m not aware of any formal objections to it, aside from the fact that questions themselves might be less common in formal writing, except rhetorically, but I’ll take Old Brixtonian’s word on it.
